# I am importing locofy code into Visual studio after i converted it from Figma design and facing this issue while I am trying to run the code

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

> info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
> info Installing the app...
> ./gradlew
>
> info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
>
> ./gradlew: line 84: cd: ${APP_HOME:-./}: No such file or directory
> error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> ./gradlew: line 84: cd: ${APP_HOME:-./}: No such file or directory.
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I have been trying since 2 days but no luck so far.

1.On running npx react-native doctor -- no errors or warnings on android.

2. I have set an environmental variable by setting APP_HOME in .zshrc
   when i try to echo it prints fine but my application doesnt run and keeps displaying ./gradlew: line 84: cd: ${APP_HOME:-./}: No such file or directory

Please help as I am new to this.